# Nestjs typeorm and @nestjs/typeorm version confilict error

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I normally was using "typeorm": "^0.2.45", and "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.3", for my projects and it was working in a good way with my boilerplate but today I'm getting this error;
MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given. Supported drivers are: "aurora-data-api", "aurora-data-api-pg", "better-sqlite3", "capacitor", "cockroachdb", "cordova", "expo", "mariadb", "mongodb", "mssql", "mysql", "nativescript", "oracle", "postgres", "react-native", "sap", "sqlite", "sqljs".
before this error when I was installing my package.json I got some errors about confilict of this packages versions so is there anybody who can say how to solve this error.
here is the my .env file and main.ts file and my error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzdMW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FueYW.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzgwB.png)

Comment: is your ormconfig set? This happens when typeorm cannot find a datasource.

Comment: I'm using .env file as ormconfig and for my structructure it suppose  to find

Comment: try logging the env variables to see if they are getting loaded

Comment: Thanks I check and I got env variables.. I don't know why and how but I paste a package-lock.json file  from old project to new one and it solved somehow. I really wish if I know why :)

Answer (score 0):

`ormconfig` support was deprecated on version `0.3.0` and will be removed on `0.4.0`.
Check this out https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/releases?page=